# Scaling numpy exponential random generator

Tags: python, numpy, random, exponential

I am trying to create random numbers that follow the exponential distribution. The numbers should be between 0 and 18353. I am using the following code:

```
np.random.exponential(2400, 400)
```

which means that the output has 400 numbers and the scale parameter is 2400. However, 2400 is my estimation of the scaling parameter by plotting the random numbers.

```
sns.kdeplot(np.random.exponential(2000, 400))
sns.kdeplot(np.random.exponential(2400, 400))
sns.kdeplot(np.random.exponential(2300, 400))

plt.legend([r"$\beta = 1$", 
            r"$\beta = 2$", 
            r"$\beta = 3$"])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Is there anyway to calculate the scale parameter so that it gives us the numbers in a specific range?

Comment: Observe that the exponential distribution has infinite support; variates can take on any positive value.

Comment: You can throw out numbers that are larger than any given value, but then the distribution is not exponential. The plot is also misleading, because the distribution has no negative values. The beta scale parameters are not 1, 2 and 3, but the values you defined previously.

Comment: @DanielTuzes Yes, that is the problem. I tried deleting out-of-range numbers but it is not a correct approach as you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't firmly restrict the upper bound of the random values drawn from an exponential distribution (see comment above).
Given the [quantile formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Quantiles) for the exponential distribution (with lambda = 1 / beta) you can calculate the scale parameter `beta` so that in average say 99.9 % of the values are less than 18353:

```
beta = -18353/np.log(1 - 0.999)
a = np.random.exponential(beta, 400)
```

Comment: Thank you. It is definitely helpful.
Do you have any idea for average? Is there a way to set the average for exponential random numbers? I know that it can go to infinity but considering 99.9% average.

Comment: Not sure if this answers your question, but the average of the exponential distribution is the parameter beta, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Properties)

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have tried to use beta and then get the average of produced data. Sometimes it was still far from beta. I was wondering if there is a more accurate way to do it. I understand that we are generating random numbers so there is no guarantee.

Comment: hm, it depends on what you understand by _far_: `np.random.exponential(beta, n).mean() - beta` will be approaching zero when you increase `n`. I'm afraid there's no better way.